# href not working in JSFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I am not able to make the href attribute work in JSFiddle. Is it a limitation of JSFiddle?

https://jsfiddle.net/ThatBoyCoder/9d0ku9vw/5/

The links should take me to another page on JSFiddle

Current code:

```
<body bgcolor="blue">
  <h2 align=center>Welcome To MathMasters</h2>
  <h3 align=center>Developed By ThatBoyCoder</h3></font>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ThatBoyCoder/zb6jmz53/15/">
    <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:150px; LEFT:160px; WIDTH:50px;  HEIGHT:50px" SRC="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/ba/c4/1d/bac41dd0a43f7ddba5321481b101d28e.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ThatBoyCoder/zb6jmz53/15/">
    <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:150px; LEFT:310px; WIDTH:50px;HEIGHT:50px" SRC="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/65/75/5e/65755e052fc8c4a8a3d1f1d68c3bf328.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ThatBoyCoder/zb6jmz53/15/">
    <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:150px; LEFT:460px; WIDTH:50px; HEIGHT:50px" SRC="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/6c/8d/40/6c8d40d75fe2477080bd02ee134c237d.jpg">
  </a>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to visit another link in that same window, but if you add `target='_blank'` to your href's, they will correctly open in a new tab